# What core Meteor methods can I call to compile a new template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I'm specifically trying to do this client side but it it can only be done server side I will use Meteor.call to return the compiled template as a string via DDP/Ajax.

My end goal is to dynamically create new templates (HTML, events, helpers, etc) at runtime. And then sometimes replace existing templates with updated ones.

Comment: did you try `UI.renderWithData(Template.foo, {bar: "baz"}) ` https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#meteorrender-has-been-removed

Comment: I need to be able to define the HTML content of the template as a string, not just the data. How can I create a brand new template from scratch and evaluate and compile it at runtime?

Comment: `UI.renderWithData` returns a string and I think it does exactly what you want. Still need an example?

Comment: `UI.renderWithData` does **not** return a string. It contains an activated template instance which must be inserted into the DOM with `UI.insert` or stringified with `UI.toHTML`. Besides, the OP is asking for a way to replace the compiled template code at runtime, which is a completely different question.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807739/meteor-how-to-save-templates-in-mongo. I found a way to compile client side but then I'm stucked. renderWithData requires a component and the compiled template is just a document (or something like that). What we need to create the component first and then I guess that UI.renderwithData and UI.insert should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The compilation of templates is done on the server, see

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars-compiler

I don't think you'd want to do this on the client because then each client may have different local templates and display things differently. You would have to send the templates to the server anyway so that other clients could get them updated as well. Same thing for helpers, etc.

Are you **sure** that you can't achieve this by defining some templates that can be shared across clients and then updating the data context? It seems you are trying to create some way for clients to produce new templates for the app, but you can accomplish this by having some sort of structured data that nests existing templates together to create custom views.