# Meteor how to save templates in mongo

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to give my users the possibility to create document templates (contracts, emails, etc.)

The best option I figured out would be to store these document templates in mongo (maybe I'm wrong...)

I've been searching for a couple of hours now but I can't figure out how to render these document template with their data context.

**Example:**

```
Template stored in Mongo: "Dear {{firstname}}"
data context: {firstname: "Tom"}
```

On Tom's website, He should read: "Dear Tom"

How can I do this?

EDIT

After some researches, I discovered a package called spacebars-compiler that brings the option to compile to the client:

```
meteor add spacebars-compiler
```

I then tried something like this:

```
Template.doctypesList.rendered = ->
  content = "<div>" + this.data.content + "</div>"
  template = Spacebars.compile content
  rendered = UI.dynamic(template,{name:"nicolas"})
  UI.insert(rendered, $(this).closest(".widget-body"))
```

but it doesn't work.

the template gets compiled but then, I don't know how to interpret it with its data context and to send it back to the web page.

**EDIT 2**

I'm getting closer thanks to Tom.

This is what I did:

```
Template.doctypesList.rendered = ->
  content = this.data.content
  console.log content
  templateName = "template_#{this.data._id}"
  Template.__define__(templateName, () -> content)
  rendered = UI.renderWithData(eval("Template.#{templateName}"),{name:"nicolas"})
  UI.insert(rendered, $("#content_" + this.data._id).get(0))
```

This works excepted the fact that the name is not injected into the template. UI.renderWithData renders the template but without the data context...

Comment: Not really possible; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24743280/586086. Templates are currently compiled on the server when Meteor starts and you'd have to send the compiled version to all connected clients. Good idea though, if Meteor sent templates over publications as well so that clients could make new templates and share them.

Comment: It is apparently possible to compile client side (see my edit above) but then I'm stuck. How can I render It?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Template[templateName]` instead of the much more convoluted `eval("Template.#{templateName}")`? What you're doing should work, but make sure you only define the template once.

Answer (score 1):

The thing your are missing is the call to (undocumented!) `Template.__define__` which requires the template name (pick something unique and clever) as the first argument and the render function which you get from your space bars compiler. When it is done you can use `{{> UI.dynamic}}` as @Slava suggested.

There is also another way to do it, by using `UI.Component` API, but I guess it's pretty unstable at the moment, so maybe I will skip this, at least for now.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. It made me make progress. I only have one issue left. See my edit 2 in the question. Rgds

Answer (score 0):

Use UI.dynamic: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/

It is fairly new and didn't make its way to docs for some reason.

Comment: I think he is asking for some way to enter a template as handlebars-style code on the client and get it compiled and ready for use. That's not what `{{> UI.dynamic}}` does...

Comment: @AndrewMao true that. To compile the template, you either need to ship spacebars to the client or store the compiled version of templates in mongo

Comment: @imslavko spacebar-compiler is already available on client, isn't it? He can make a package and access it on client. I wonder if storing compiled template would be the right choice. I mean right now Spacebars converts html to htmljs and uses Template.template_name.lookup for getting the data, this or something else might change in future. I think best for him would be to store the template in mongo and compile it on client. Correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: @channikhabra I believe that all the templates->js conversion is happenning on the build step

Comment: @imslavko yes meteor does that on build time. But we can do that ourselves from a package by using spacebars-compiler. I have done that in a package

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve what you want, but I would do it like this:

You're probably already using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), if not Meteor has core package for it.

You could use underscore templates (http://underscorejs.org/#template) like this:

`var templateString = 'Dear <%= firstname %>'`

and later compile it using

`_.template(templateString, {firstname: "Tom"})`

to get `Dear Tom`.

Of course you can store `templateString` in MongoDB in the meantime.
You can set delimiters to whatever you want, `<%= %>` is just the default.

Comment: Good idea but I'd like to stick to the meteor templating engine though because I would like to use some Meteor features.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled template is essentially htmljs notation Meteor uses (or so I suppose) and it uses `Template.template_name.lookup` to render correct data. Check in console if `Template.template_name.lookup("data_helper")()` returns the correct data.

I recently had to solve this exact (or similar) problem of compiling templates client side. You need to make sure the order of things is like this:

- Compiled template is present on client
- Template data is present (verify with `Template.template_name.lookup("data_name")()` )
- Render the template on page now

To compile the template, as @apendua have suggested, use (this is how I use it and it works for me)

```
Template.__define__(name, eval(Spacebars.compile(
            newHtml, {
                isTemplate: true,
                sourceName: 'Template "' + name + '"'
            }
        )));
```

After this you need to make sure the data you want to render in template is available before you actually render the template on page. This is what I use for rendering template on page:

```
UI.DomRange.insert(UI.render(Template.template_name).dom, document.body);
```

Although my use case for rendering templates client side is somewhat different (my task was to live update the changed template overriding meteor's hot code push), but this worked best among different methods of rendering the template.

You can check my very early stage package which does this here: https://github.com/channikhabra/meteor-live-update/blob/master/js/live-update.js

I am fairly new to real-world programming so my code might be ugly, but may be it'll give you some pointers to solve your problem. (If you find me doing something stupid in there, or see something which is better done some other way, please feel free to drop a comment. That's the only way I get feedback for improvement as I am new and essentially code alone sitting in my dark corner).